# Get Api is not working properly

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession, afnetworking-2

i am working on get api when hit the api in app i am not getting updated response when i remove the app from simulator and device its working fine.guys what i am doing wrong please help me.i have already tried Afnetworking simple Api nsurl session.

```
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mysponsers.com/m/comments/publicpost/674"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
    [httpClient getPath:strURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    id    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSLog(@"RESPONSE--->1%@",json);
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError *error) {
        //fail!
        NSLog(@"Error String is %@", error.localizedDescription);

    }];
```

Here is the code i am using afnetworkikng for hitting the api.
    Thank You

Comment: dont tag swift for objC questions

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking you are using?

Comment: Jynesh i am using afnetworking 2.0

Comment: Please try with v3.0.

Comment: NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mysponsers.com/m/comments/publicpost/674"];
  
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
   
   NSError *error = nil;
  NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
  id    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:oResponseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
  NSLog(@"oResponseData%@",oResponseData);

Comment: also i had try this one

Answer (score 0):

You can try with latest version of `AFNetworking` library or you can simply use this code also.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysponsers.com/m/comments/publicpost/674"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can install or update AFNetworking via cocoapods by adding this (pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0') in your pod file.

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    // Change your api content-type here:
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

    [manager GET:@"{ Write your url here }"
      parameters:nil
        progress:nil
         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Success response: %@", response);
         }
         failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)operation.response;
             NSLog(@"Failure response: %@", response);
         }];
```